# acid-state example error

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, acid-state

I'm trying to start using `acid-state` for a project, but I'm running into trouble running the demos.

Running [`HelloWorld.hs`](http://mirror.seize.it/acid-state/examples/HelloWorld.hs) from [this example collection](http://mirror.seize.it/acid-state/examples/) on my 64-bit box gives me the errors

```
acid-state.hs:26:7:
    No instance for (MonadState
                       HelloWorldState (Update HelloWorldState))
      arising from a use of `put'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (MonadState HelloWorldState (Update HelloWorldState))
    In the expression: put (HelloWorldState newValue)
    In an equation for `writeState':
        writeState newValue = put (HelloWorldState newValue)

acid-state.hs:29:43:
    No instance for (MonadReader
                       HelloWorldState (Query HelloWorldState))
      arising from a use of `ask'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (MonadReader HelloWorldState (Query HelloWorldState))
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: HelloWorldState string <- ask
    In the expression:
      do { HelloWorldState string <- ask;
           return string }
    In an equation for `queryState':
        queryState
          = do { HelloWorldState string <- ask;
                 return string }
```

The same thing happens with [`HelloWorldNoTH.hs`](http://mirror.seize.it/acid-state/examples/HelloWorldNoTH.hs) as well. Neither error manifests on a 32-bit system. Any ideas what's going on here? Did I fail to install (or improperly install) some required component?

I'm running "`The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1`" on 64-bit Debian Wheezy (installed via the `haskell-platform` package), with Cabal `0.14.0`. The machine itself is a 64-bit Core i3. The 32-bit machine (which ran the demo successfully) differs in no non-obvious way.

Comment: This question and your previous one (both problems importing monad transformer instances) make me think something is broken in your/Debian's haskell-platform installation.  Possibly useless suggestions: (1) run `ghc-pkg check`, (2) `cabal install hsenv`, create a new project directory and hsenv, `cabal update && cabal install cabal`, `cabal update` with the new cabal (0.16), and finally `cabal install acid-state happstack-server`.

Comment: I can confirm that the `HelloWorld.hs` code example compiles fine using the Debian packaged stuff. So maybe try `rm -rf ~/.ghc` and install `libghc-acid-state-dev`, avoiding compiling any library by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with which architecture you're running on (sorry for jumping to conclusions).

Turns out that I had some misconfiguration, or possibly some conflicting `cabal` libraries installed. Clearing out my `.ghc`, followed by a re-install of the appropriate library did the trick. If you're on Debian or comparable:

```
rm -r ~/.ghc/*
cabal install acid-state
```